# Forgot to set "in production" to YES when releasing app using Urban Airship

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I just released an iOS app and I noticed that all my users' devices were being registered to the development version of my app in Urban Airship.  When I checked the app code I saw that I forgot to set the "in production" boolean to YES.  By the time that I get an app update approved I will have a couple of thousand devices registered to the development app.  I have a couple of questions:

1. Will the users who agreed to push notifications already be asked again when I update the app?
2. Can I send the hundreds of users I have signed up on the development app notifications in the meantime?

Comment: Notice that the AppStore is in a holiday shutdown until December 27th.

Comment: yes, that is why I estimated several thousand registered devices by the time an update is live.

Comment: This is probably a better question to be asked of the UrbanAirship folks on their support site.  To check if you can send notifications to the dev accounts, just locate your own ID and send a test push to yourself.